# Combine two lines by different criteria with change the column names in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I had a collection with data like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "tenant": "SOFIA",
        "thirdParty": "SOFIA|ANDROS|juridical-entity",
        "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Pharmacie",
        "year": 2018
    },
    "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Pharmacie",
    "year": 2018,
    "numberOfActs": 160,
    "totalRealCharges": 882.3299999999999,
    "totalSSReimbursement": 521.63,
    "totalDelegatePayment": 360.42,
    "totalOtherReimbursement": 0,
    "insuredUsersNumber": 80
},
{
    "_id": {
        "tenant": "SOFIA",
        "thirdParty": "SOFIA|ANDROS|juridical-entity",
        "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Pharmacie",
        "year": 2019
    },
    "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Pharmacie",
    "year": 2019,
    "numberOfActs": 100,
    "totalRealCharges": 784.20,
    "totalSSReimbursement": 122,
    "totalDelegatePayment": 230.35,
    "totalOtherReimbursement": 12,
    "insuredUsersNumber": 56
}
,
{
    "_id": {
        "tenant": "SOFIA",
        "thirdParty": "SOFIA|ANDROS|juridical-entity",
        "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Optique",
        "year": 2019
    },
    "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Optique",
    "year": 2019,
    "numberOfActs": 33,
    "totalRealCharges": 6282,
    "totalSSReimbursement": 158.5,
    "totalDelegatePayment": 4919.46,
    "totalOtherReimbursement": 270,
    "insuredUsersNumber": 21
}
,
{
    "_id": {
        "tenant": "SOFIA",
        "thirdParty": "SOFIA|ANDROS|juridical-entity",
        "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Hospitalisation",
        "year": 2019
    },
    "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Hospitalisation",
    "year": 2019,
    "numberOfActs": 1437,
    "totalRealCharges": 129477.12,
    "totalSSReimbursement": 60697.87,
    "totalDelegatePayment": 63864.41,
    "totalOtherReimbursement": 3523.2999999999997,
    "insuredUsersNumber": 279
}
```

I need to produce the following result:

```
{
    "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Pharmacie",
    "numberOfActs_previousYear": 160,
    "totalRealCharges_previousYear": 882.3299999999999,
    "totalSSReimbursement_previousYear": 521.63,
    "totalDelegatePayment_previousYear": 360.42,
    "totalOtherReimbursement_previousYear": 0,
    "insuredUsersNumber_previousYear": 80, 

    "numberOfActs": 100,
    "totalRealCharges": 784.20,
    "totalSSReimbursement": 122,
    "totalDelegatePayment": 230.35,
    "totalOtherReimbursement": 12,
    "insuredUsersNumber": 56

},
{
    "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Optique",
    "numberOfActs_previousYear": 33,
    "totalRealCharges_previousYear": 6282,
    "totalSSReimbursement_previousYear": 158.5,
    "totalDelegatePayment_previousYear": 4919.46,
    "totalOtherReimbursement_previousYear": 270,
    "insuredUsersNumber_previousYear": 21,

    "numberOfActs": 0,
    "totalRealCharges": 0,
    "totalSSReimbursement": 0,
    "totalDelegatePayment": 0,
    "totalOtherReimbursement": 0,
    "insuredUsersNumber": 0
}
,
{
    "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Hospitalisation",
    "numberOfActs_previousYear": 1437,
    "totalRealCharges_previousYear": 129477.12,
    "totalSSReimbursement_previousYear": 60697.87,
    "totalDelegatePayment_previousYear": 63864.41,
    "totalOtherReimbursement_previousYear": 3523.2999999999997,
    "insuredUsersNumber_previousYear": 279,

    "numberOfActs": 0,
    "totalRealCharges": 0,
    "totalSSReimbursement": 0,
    "totalDelegatePayment": 0,
    "totalOtherReimbursement": 0,
    "insuredUsersNumber": 0
}
```

I.e. I want to combine every 2 lines by `medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel` and get all fields for the current year and all fields for the previous one, stored it with different names and If the line for previous year not exist to get 0 for all of the fields.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: If I group by `medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel` and use $mergeObjects it will overlape the fields, but I want to save it with different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) in the sum:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel: "$medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel"
      },
      numberOfActs_previousYear: {
        $sum: {
          // if year is 2018 then value is numberOfActs otherwise zero
          $cond: [{ '$eq': ['$year', 2018] }, "$numberOfActs", 0] 
        }
      },
      numberOfActs: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ '$eq': ['$year', 2019] }, "$numberOfActs", 0]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Hospitalisation"
    },
    "numberOfActs": 1437,
    "numberOfActs_previousYear": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Optique"
    },
    "numberOfActs": 33,
    "numberOfActs_previousYear": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "medicalreimbursementDateFamlyLabel": "Pharmacie"
    },
    "numberOfActs": 100,
    "numberOfActs_previousYear": 160
  }
]
```